# Proper code in Java to calculate floor(n^(1/exp)). WIth n and exp both integers

Tags: java, rounding

How should I write this function. Argument **in** is in [2,2^60] and **exp** in [2,60].
QUEST1 : How to avoid the MESSY test ? I could not make it with Big decimal.This is like an exponential version of the old classic bug ( 1 multiply by 3 then divided by 3 is not always 1).
QUEST2 : How to code it if in  is much bigger ( 2^90)
See code below. If needed I can post the code that test it all.

```
/** @param in input 
  * @param exp exponent >=2 
  * @return floor[in^(1/exp)] */
public static long floorOk1( final long in , final int exp) {  
    final long ret = (long) Math.floor(Math.pow(in,1.0/exp));
    if ( Math.pow(ret+1,exp) <= in ) CORRECTIONS++; // add 1 needed 
        return  ( Math.pow(ret+1,exp) <=in ) ? ret+1L: ret ;   
}
// All OK floorBAD(25 ,2)=5 = floorULP(25 ,2)    
// floorULP(125,3)=5 OK ,BUT floorBAD(125,3)=4 (must be 5 as 5^3=125)  
// floorULP(24389,3)=28 and  floorBAD(24389,3)=28  BOTH WRONG (should be 29 as  29^3= 24389 ) 
/**  (24389,3)->28 is WRONG should be 29 ,  BUT ( 125/3)=5 ok */ 
public static long floorULP( final long in , final int exp) { 
    final double val = Math.pow(in,1.0/exp) ;
    return (long) ( Math.floor(val+Math.ulp(val))); 
} 
/** Arguments (125/3) and (24389,3) -> WRONG results: 1 less than expected. */ 
    public static long floorBAD( final long in , final int exp) { return (long) Math.floor(Math.pow(in,1.0/exp)); } 

    /** Args(in,exp)= (125  ,3) ==> floorBAD is wrong but floorULP is OK 
     *  Args(in,exp)= (24389,3) ==> floorBAD is wrong AND  floorULP also WRONG 
     *  NOTE : WE HAVE 5^3= 125 ; 29^3= 24389  **/
    public static void smallDifferenceTest() { 
        System.out.println(" floorOk1(25,2)    =" + floorOk1(25 ,2)   + " == BAD(25   ,2)=" + floorBAD(25 ,2)   + " Ok=" + (floorBAD(25 ,2)==floorOk1(25 ,2)) ) ;
        System.out.println(" floorOk1(25,2)    =" + floorOk1(25 ,2)   + " == ULP(25   ,2)=" + floorULP(25 ,2)   + " Ok=" + (floorULP(25 ,2)==floorOk1(25 ,2)) ) ;

        System.out.println(" floorOk1(125,3)   =" + floorOk1(125,3)   + " != BAD(125  ,3)=" + floorBAD(125,3)   + " Ok=" + (floorBAD(125,3)==floorOk1(125,3)) ) ;
        System.out.println(" floorOk1(125,3)   =" + floorOk1(125,3)   + " == ULP(125  ,3)=" + floorULP(125,3)   + " Ok=" + (floorULP(125,3)==floorOk1(125,3)) ) ;

        System.out.println(" floorOk1(24389,3) =" + floorOk1(24389,3) + " != ULP(24389,3)=" + floorULP(24389,3) + " Ok=" + (floorULP(24389,3)==floorOk1(24389,3)) ) ; ;
        System.out.println(" floorOk1(24389,3) =" + floorOk1(24389,3) + " != BAD(24389,3)=" + floorBAD(24389,3) + " Ok=" + (floorBAD(24389,3)==floorOk1(24389,3)) ) ; ;
    }
/*
Tests result are: 
 floorOk1(25,2)    =5 == BAD(25   ,2)=5 Ok=true
 floorOk1(25,2)    =5 == ULP(25   ,2)=5 Ok=true
 floorOk1(125,3)   =5 != BAD(125  ,3)=4 Ok=false
 floorOk1(125,3)   =5 == ULP(125  ,3)=5 Ok=true
 floorOk1(24389,3) =29 != ULP(24389,3)=28 Ok=false
 floorOk1(24389,3) =29 != BAD(24389,3)=28 Ok=false
*/
```

I mainly tried BigDecimal as an alternative found one solution:

```
public static long floorDEC( final long in , final int exp) { 
 return new BigDecimal(Math.pow(in,1.0/exp),MathContext.DECIMAL32).longValue();
    }
```

Comment: `n^(1/x)` is the same as the `x-th root of n`. So for this special requirement, you can just iterate over `i = 1.. z` and calculate `i^x` until `i^x  > n`. Then your result is `i-1`

Comment: @derpirscher The loop is much to slow.

Comment: @user16320675 ULP not OK : See modification I have add a floorULP() in code : it does not work ( ok with 125= 5^3 but NOT with 24389=29^3

Comment: Here is a one line function that works  :given arguments (in,exp ) the function will      :       return  new BigDecimal(Math.pow(in,1.0/exp),MathContext.DECIMAL32.).longValue();  //     Note: DECIMAL64 as any precision out of [7,15] does not work why ??